# Changing multidimensional array key value having his keys in another array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays:

```
$array = [
    'application' => [
        'foo' => [
            'bar' => 1
        ]
    ]
];

$array_2 = [
    0 => 'application',
    1 => 'foo',
    2 => 'bar'
];
```

*How can I change the value of the first array knowning that the last key in the second array is the key who's value must be changed in the first array?*

As you can see the second array contains all the keys from the first array. I want to do something like:

```
$array[$array_2] = 2;
```

... I suppose I must create a `for` loop?

---

For example, if I want to change the `bar` key value, I must do:

```
$array['application']['foo']['bar'] = 2;
```

... but I don't know which key I must change, I only have an array containing keys, and the last key in the list is the key that's value must be changed.

Comment: "*How can I change the value of the first array having only the second array that contains the first array keys.*" - Not sure what you're trying to achieve. Can you add the expected output to the question?

Comment: [This may inspire you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14704984/best-way-for-dot-notation-access-to-multidimensional-array-in-php), but don't be afraid to write your own code, you need either a `for` or a recursive approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build a recursive function, or use a reference:

```
$result =& $array;

foreach($array_2 as $key) {
    $result =& $result[$key];
}
$result = 2;

print_r($array);
```

Comment: It's just what I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This will do it, although not sure what you are trying to achieve.

```
$array[$array_2[0]][$array_2[1]][$array_2[2]] = 2;
```

Comment: Something like that, but more 'automatic'. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Recursively add the keys. This works -

```
function get_keys($arr, &$keys){
    $keys = array_merge($keys,array_keys($arr));
    foreach($arr as $a){
        if(is_array($a)){
            get_keys($a, $keys);
        }
    }
}
$array = Array(
    'application' => Array(
        'foo' => Array(
            'bar' => 1
        )
    )
);
$keys = Array();
get_keys($array, $keys);
var_dump($keys);
```

OUTPUT-

```
array
  0 => string 'application' (length=11)
  1 => string 'foo' (length=3)
  2 => string 'bar' (length=3)
```