# Access a deeply and multi value of multidimensional array with dot notation

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to access multidimensional array with dot notation deeply multiple values

Here is Example situation

```
$arrays = ['a' => [
    [
         'b' => 'Hello',
         'c' => 'Not now'
    ],
    [
         'b' => 'Call Again',
         'c' => 'Not now'
    ]
],
     'd' => 'With Me'
];
$result = resolve($arrays, ['a.b[]','a.d']);
echo $result;

// expected value string
// Hello, Call Again, With Me
```

For the function

> resolve()

I try as this reference link https://stackoverflow.com/a/14706302/4476788 but not what I expected.

I get array result with one value of **b** array under the **a**

Comment: Can you install `illuminate/support` package? You can use [`Arr::get()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-array-get) and any other useful helpers from it.

Comment: This reads like you are trying to implement a macro language to access array values. Why?

Comment: Notice that the `resolve` function doesn't get array as second argument. And also, it doesn't support the `[]` operator

Comment: @arkascha to easy access value of array and make it to string

Comment: @dWinder got it, I try to modify the function but still not what I expected, can't find the best logic for it

Comment: You add quite a lot of complexity that way, since you basically have to implement a language interpreter for this. Again: why? Why not simply access the array values in ordinary fashion?

Comment: @arkascha in the end, I will use it on google translate, as far I know google translate cannot translate array/object, that's why I need to convert the array values in a string with custom separator so I can make a one time translate using google API translator with those function