# use saved string as target to object content

Tags: php, json

We're working with lots of json data and trying to define via strings variable what parts of it to use.

So i'm trying to convert a string to an object path to an items content.

This works...

```
<?php 
$pmdd_ds_json_obj = json_decode($pmdd_ds_json_data);
echo $pmdd_ds_json_obj[0]->title->rendered; 
// shows "Wisconsin Investment Board"
?>
```

but i can't seem to get this to load the same as above.

```
$num = 0;
$root =  "pmdd_ds_json_obj[$num]->";
$content = "title->rendered"
$obj_content = ${$root.$content};

// tried other approached too.
echo $root.$content;
echo ${$root.$content};
echo ${"$root.$content"};
```

Is what i'm doing even possible? Tried a lot of variations and need a fresh set of eyes!

## json data

```
[{
    "date": "2019-07-04T10:21:15",
    "title": {
        "rendered": "Wisconsin Investment Board"
    },
    "_links": {
        "self": [{
            "href": "https:\/\/refi.global\/europe\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/posts\/309891"
        }]
    }
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Variable variables won't process the array key, or arrow operators, like you've tried. You could do what you're trying to do by using `eval()`, but don't :P

However, `json_decode` accepts a flag to return an associative array rather than `stdClass` objects. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

`$foo = json_decode($json, true);`

Once you have that, you could get the value you want by using a function to resolve an array value by dot notation, which can be stored as a variable. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14706302/2286736

```
<?php

$json = '[{
    "date": "2019-07-04T10:21:15",
    "title": {
        "rendered": "Wisconsin Investment Board"
    }
}]';

// decode as associative array
$pmdd_ds_json_obj = json_decode($json, true);

/**
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/a/14706302/2286736
 */
function resolve(array $a, $path, $default = null) {
    $current = $a;
    $p = strtok($path, '.');

    while ($p !== false) {
        if (!isset($current[$p])) {
            return $default;
        }
        $current = $current[$p];
        $p = strtok('.');
    }

    return $current;
}

// key variable
$key = '0.title.rendered';

// value can be resolved by the dot notation path
$value = resolve($pmdd_ds_json_obj, $key);
var_dump($value); // Wisconsin Investment Board
```

Additional changes to the `resolve()` function to allow it to accept objects as well:

```
$json = '[{
    "date": "2019-07-04T10:21:15",
    "title": {
        "rendered": "Wisconsin Investment Board"
    },
    "_links": {
        "self": [{
            "href": "https:\/\/refi.global\/europe\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/posts\/309891"
        }]
    }
}]';

// decode as normal (with stdClass)
$pmdd_ds_json_obj = json_decode($json);

function resolve($a, $path, $default = null) {
    $current = $a;
    $p = strtok($path, '.');

    while ($p !== false) {
        if (
            (is_array($current) && !isset($current[$p]))
            || (is_object($current) && !isset($current->$p))
        ) {
            return $default;
        }
        $current = is_array($current) ? $current[$p] : $current->$p;
        $p = strtok('.');
    }

    return $current;
}

// key variable
$key = '0._links.self.0.href';

// value can be resolved by the dot notation path
$value = resolve($pmdd_ds_json_obj, $key);
```

Comment: thanks Ben. I did see this but wanted to stick to objects. I've tested this and it doesn't seem to do arrays in arrays.? ie '0._links.0.self.href' is that right?

Comment: In the case of your updated JSON, it would be `0._links.self.0.href` ('self' is the array, not 'links'). I've updated the answer with some amends to the `resolve()` function to allow it to accept objects as well, so you don't need to use the assoc flag on `json_decode()` if you don't want to :)